# Why does updating a record retrieved using the db.table[id] syntax not work?

Tags: web2py

I have tried these four ways of updating a record. The first two are described in the book. The third one looks the same as the second one but it doesn't work. And the fourth one looks the same as the first one. But it doesnt work either. What are the differences here that I am missing?

```
    DeckID = 1

    db(db.Deck.id == DeckID).update(CardCriteria='This works')

    db.Deck[DeckID] = dict(CardCriteria='This works too')

    rec = db.Deck[DeckID]
    rec = dict(CardCriteria='This DOESNT work')

    db.Deck[DeckID].update(CardCriteria='This DOESNT work either')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using `update`

```
db(db.Deck.id == DeckID).update(CardCriteria='This works')
```

In the above, `db(db.Deck.id == DeckID)` is a DAL `Set` object -- it's `update` method executes a database update. However, `db.Deck[DeckID]` is a DAL `Row` object -- it acts like a dictionary, so it's `update` method simply updates the `Row` object itself (it does not execute a database update). To execute a database update, the `Row` object has the `update_record` method:

```
db.Deck[DeckID].update_record(CardCriteria='This works')
```

You can also update the `Row` object locally and then call `update_record` with no arguments, and it will send the local updates to the database:

```
rec = db.Deck[DeckID]
rec.update(CardCriteria='This works')
rec.update_record()
```

### Using `__setitem__`

```
db.Deck[DeckID] = dict(CardCriteria='This works too')
```

In the above, the assignment to `db.Deck[DeckID]` triggers the `__setitem__` magic method of the `Row` object, which results a database update rather than a `DeckId` key being added to the `db.Deck` table object. However, in this line:

```
rec = dict(CardCriteria='This DOESNT work')
```

you are simply re-assigning the `rec` variable to be a dictionary (there is no triggering of the `__setitem__` magic method because you are not using `object[key] = value` syntax).

Note, this same issue applies outside of the context of the `DAL`:

```
>>> mydict = dict(mykey=1)
>>> myvalue = mydict['mykey']
>>> mydict['mykey'] = 2 # Here we update the "mykey" key of `mydict`.
>>> myvalue = 3 # Here we assign a new value to `myvalue` (no effect on `mydict`)
>>> mydict # Notice the `myvalue` assignment above did not affect `mydict`
{'mykey': 2}
```

Comment: Excellent answer Anthony. Thanks for the clarification. It's worthy of inclusion in the book!